# Is it natural/correct to use "while" to describe that two things are achieved

Tags: conjunctions

> 1. This method will reduce cost while improving quality.
> 2. This method will reduce cost and also improve quality.

Could you advise me on whether which of the above is better?

I want only to say the method can reduce cost and improve quality, but I am urged to use "while" when translating my language into English.  If using "while" will cause no problem, I want to use "while".

Comment: Both sentences are fine and mean the same thing. Personally, I would say _this method will reduce cost **while also** improving quality_ but there's nothing wrong with either of your sentences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I see i, there's almost no difference between the two. The only thing that comes to my mind is that when saying

> This method will reduce cost and also improve quality.

equally stresses both the first and second part of the sentence.

Meanwhile, saying

> This method will reduce cost while **also** improving quality

has a slight inclination towards reducing costs being more important than improving quality.

Apart from that, both the sentences seem very similar.